# Need fiber connection between switches

Tags: ethernet, fiber

[image]What kind of fiber connection does the top switch use?  I know the bottom switch uses a multi-mode MTRJ connector but I want to connect the bottom switch to the top switch.  This is practice for the CCNA exam.  I am new to fiber cable connections :)

Thank you!

Comment: Just from searching google, all your questions answered: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9T0AzeWM_F4

Comment: So is the top connector an LC or an SC??  They both look so similar I can't tell.

Comment: It looks like the same size on the video as nothing is to scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Cisco's Datasheet](http://www.andovercg.com/datasheets/cisco-2900-series-catalyst-switch.pdf):

> 100BaseFX ports: SC connector, 50/125- and 62.5/125-micron multimode fiber-optic cabling (only on Catalyst 2924C
>   and 2-port and 4-port 100BaseFX modules)